# typesetting chains of maps

Tags: tikz-chains

[image]

Can anyone help me of how to construct this chain in Latex?

Answer (score 3):

Use `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={minimum height=2em}}]
0\arrow[r] & \frac{E}{\phi} \arrow[r,"\delta"] \arrow[d] &  H^{1} \arrow[r,"\rho"]\arrow[rd,"\bar{\rho}"] \arrow[d,"Res"] &  H^{1} \arrow[r]\arrow[d,"Res"] & 0\\
0 \arrow[r] & \Pi\frac{E}{\phi} \arrow[r,"\rho_{\nu}"] & \Pi_{\nu}H^{1} \arrow[r] & \Pi_{\nu}H^{1} \arrow[r] & 0
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Type the remaining symbols yourself. :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I have tried this code but it gives me errors. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @P.D. May be you have old tex distro. Try updating it so that you have recent packages.